# Customising jquery Datatable text property

Tags: jquery, datatables

I was just wondering if there is a way to customize the default text in the datatables like `sLengthMenu`, `sZeroRecords`, `sInfo`, etc.

I want to change the font and color of the text of the above properties. I did not get any reference related to this in the [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) site.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you have the i18n component there: [Translations](http://datatables.net/usage/i18n)

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "oLanguage": {
       "sLengthMenu": "custom length",
       "sInfo": "custom  info",
       "sZeroRecords": "<p style='color:red;'>custom no records</p>",
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yeah, the text in the properties can be customized. But here im talking about customizing the font and size of the text. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try putting HTML there? like: "sZeroRecords": "<p style='color:red;'>custom no records</p>",